# pairing and calculating the hours of checkTypes

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

[Continuing from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809378/labeling-checktypes-for-biometric-attendance), I have a table named `Attendancelogs` which has all the sorted logs CHeckTypes `In` and `Out` accordingly. (Thanks to @StephenMuecke the previous question was pretty much resolved) However, what I am trying to achieve next is to make a pairList of all the `In` and `Out` in a particular period (`StartDate` and `EndDate`) and then calculate the total hours of the employee.

[Different Cases, already been taken care of in the previous question](http://ibb.co/b8f0HS)

I have two method, one called `getSingleDevicePairs(int EnrollNumber, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)` which creates the `pairList` and the second method `getTimeSpentEachDay(List<Pair> pairList)` which calculates the total hours of each day.

Pair.cs

```
  public class Pair {
      public int id { get; set; }
      public int RegisterationId { get; set; }
      public int EmpID { get; set; }
      public DateTime InnDateTime { get; set; }
      public DateTime OutDateTime { get; set; }
  }

  public List<Pair> getSingleDevicePairs(int EnrollNumber, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate) {
      DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
      List<Pair> pairList = new List<Pair>();
      var logs = db.AttendanceLogs.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber && x.Date >= StartDate &&
            x.Date <= EndDate && x.isIgnore != true && (x.CheckType == "In" || x.CheckType == "Out")).Distinct().ToList();

      int loopEnd = 0;
      bool oddLogs = false;

      if (logs.Count % 2 == 0) {
          loopEnd = logs.Count;
      } else {
          loopEnd = logs.Count - 1;
          oddLogs = true;
      }

      bool inn = true;

      if (loopEnd > 1) {
          Pair pair = new Pair();

          for (int v = 0; v < loopEnd; v++) {

              if (inn) {
                  pair.InnDateTime = logs[v].DateTime;
                  inn = false;
              } else {
                  pair.OutDateTime = logs[v].DateTime;
                  inn = true;
                  pairList.Add(pair);
                  pair = new Pair();
              }
          }
      }

      Bogus bogus = new Bogus();
      DateTime bogusDate = new DateTime();

      if (oddLogs) {
          bogus.MachineNum = logs[logs.Count - 1].DeviceID;
          bogus.RegisterationId = logs[logs.Count - 1].RegisterationId;
          bogus.DateTime = logs[logs.Count - 1].DateTime;
          bogusDate = logs[logs.Count - 1].DateTime;
      }

      return pairList;
  }
```

^I changed the above method with different approach, since the above approach would mess up with `Case 1` shown in the link above.

```
     public List<Pair> getSingleDevicePairs(int EnrollNumber, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate) {
         DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
         List<Pair> pairList = new List<Pair>();
         var logs = db.AttendanceLogs.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber && x.Date >= StartDate &&
                x.Date <= EndDate && x.isIgnore != true && (x.CheckType == "In" || x.CheckType == "Out")).Distinct().ToList();

          bool isCheck = false;
          Pair pair = new Pair();
          DateTime previous = logs.FirstOrDefault().DateTime;

          foreach (var log in logs) {

              if (!isCheck) {
                  pair.InnDateTime = log.DateTime;
                  isCheck = true;
              } else {
                  pair.OutDateTime = log.DateTime;
                  isCheck = false;
              }
              pairList.Add(pair);
              pair = new Pair();
          }

              return pairList;
        }
```

^This approach again will fail at Case 1 as it is sequentially adding `In` and `Out` in the pairList.

```
public List<DateAndTime> getTimeSpentEachDay(List<Pair> pairList) {
    List<DateAndTime> list = new List<DateAndTime>();

    if (pairList.Count > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < pairList.Count; i++) {
            TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Zero;
            // bool flag = false;
            int result = -1;

            do {
                span = span + (pairList[i].OutDateTime - pairList[i].InnDateTime);
                result = -1;

                if (i < pairList.Count - 1) {
                    DateTime p = (DateTime)pairList[i].InnDateTime;
                    DateTime q = (DateTime)pairList[i + 1].InnDateTime;

                    result = DateTime.Compare(p.Date, q.Date);
                }

                if (result == 0) {
                    i++;
                    //  flag = true;
                }
            } while (result == 0);

            //if (i == pairList.Count - 1)
            //{
            //    span = span + (pairList[i].OutDateTime - pairList[i].InnDateTime) ?? TimeSpan.Zero;
            //}


            DateAndTime dnt = new DateAndTime();
            dnt.date = ((DateTime)pairList[i].InnDateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            dnt.Time = span;
            list.Add(dnt);
        }
    }

    return list.ToList();
}
```

I am trying to get total hours for each pair as well as a way to take the odd `In`'s together which I can display on the calendar.

Below is an image of the calendar view for an employee which displays only the paired hours, I even want to show a `In` that would indicate the employee that he either forgot to check out or a missing entry was made.

*Lets say he had a checkin for 9th April of around 08:00 PM that had no Check out on that day and also in the NightersLimit (12 AM - 7 AM) then there should be a single line displayed on the calendar which can only happen if I bring the bogus record for a day from previous method.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the `getTimeSpentEachDay();` just a little changes in the `getSingleDevicePairs();` method, your first approach fails since it eliminates the last entry of the logs in case of an odd number and your second approach fails since it is not taking account of the sequence the logs are stored in the table.

```
public List<Pair> getSingleDevicePairs(int EnrollNumber, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, int? missingEntry)
{
    var logs = db.AttendanceLogs.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber && 
               x.Date >= StartDate && x.Date <= EndDate && x.isIgnore != true 
               && (x.CheckType == "In" || x.CheckType == "Out")).Distinct().ToList();

            if (logs.Count > 0)
            {
                bool isCheck = false;
                Pair pair = new Pair();
                DateTime previous = logs.FirstOrDefault().DateTime;

                foreach (var log in logs)
                {
                    if (!isCheck)
                    {
                        if (log.CheckType == "In")
                        {
                            pair.InnDateTime = log.DateTime;
                            isCheck = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (log.CheckType == "Out")
                        {
                            pair.OutDateTime = log.DateTime;
                            isCheck = false;
                            pairList.Add(pair);
                            pair = new Pair();

                        }
                        if (pair.OutDateTime == DateTime.MinValue)
                        {
                            pair.InnDateTime = log.DateTime;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            return pairList;
        }
```

This completes the pair only when there is an `Out` for an `In`.